# Is there a way to insert a wpf window as child of another one

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to put an wpf window inside my main window.

i tried making an object then passing the window content to it like so

```
childWindow child = new childWindow();
object obj = child.content;
child.content = null;
child.Close();
myGrid.Children.Add((UIElement)obj);
```

but i want it to move inside the mainwindow(like draging and move).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall where I picked this up from but it works great. It acts like a window inside of another container.

XAML Usage First

```
<util:DragCanvas Panel.ZIndex="1" Visibility="{Binding ShowCustomerApprovals, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter1}, FallbackValue=Hidden}"></unil:DragCanvas>
```

The Class

```
public class DragCanvas : Canvas


{
#region Data

// Stores a reference to the UIElement currently being dragged by the user.
private UIElement elementBeingDragged;

// Keeps track of where the mouse cursor was when a drag operation began.       
private Point origCursorLocation;

// The offsets from the DragCanvas' edges when the drag operation began.
private double origHorizOffset, origVertOffset;

// Keeps track of which horizontal and vertical offset should be modified for the drag element.
private bool modifyLeftOffset, modifyTopOffset;

// True if a drag operation is underway, else false.
private bool isDragInProgress;

#endregion // Data

#region Attached Properties

#region CanBeDragged

public static readonly DependencyProperty CanBeDraggedProperty;

public static bool GetCanBeDragged(UIElement uiElement)
{
  if (uiElement == null)
    return false;

  return (bool)uiElement.GetValue(CanBeDraggedProperty);
}

public static void SetCanBeDragged(UIElement uiElement, bool value)
{
  if (uiElement != null)
    uiElement.SetValue(CanBeDraggedProperty, value);
}

#endregion // CanBeDragged

#endregion // Attached Properties

#region Dependency Properties

public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowDraggingProperty;
public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowDragOutOfViewProperty;

#endregion // Dependency Properties

#region Static Constructor

static DragCanvas()
{
  AllowDraggingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "AllowDragging",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(DragCanvas),
    new PropertyMetadata(true));

  AllowDragOutOfViewProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "AllowDragOutOfView",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(DragCanvas),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

  CanBeDraggedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "CanBeDragged",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(DragCanvas),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(true));
}

#endregion // Static Constructor

#region Constructor

/// <summary>
/// Initializes a new instance of DragCanvas.  UIElements in
/// the DragCanvas will immediately be draggable by the user.
/// </summary>
public DragCanvas()
{
}

#endregion // Constructor

#region Interface

#region AllowDragging

/// <summary>
/// Gets/sets whether elements in the DragCanvas should be draggable by the user.
/// The default value is true.  This is a dependency property.
/// </summary>
public bool AllowDragging
{
  get { return (bool)base.GetValue(AllowDraggingProperty); }
  set { base.SetValue(AllowDraggingProperty, value); }
}

#endregion // AllowDragging

#region AllowDragOutOfView

/// <summary>
/// Gets/sets whether the user should be able to drag elements in the DragCanvas out of
/// the viewable area.  The default value is false.  This is a dependency property.
/// </summary>
public bool AllowDragOutOfView
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowDragOutOfViewProperty); }
  set { SetValue(AllowDragOutOfViewProperty, value); }
}

#endregion // AllowDragOutOfView

#region BringToFront / SendToBack

/// <summary>
/// Assigns the element a z-index which will ensure that 
/// it is in front of every other element in the Canvas.
/// The z-index of every element whose z-index is between 
/// the element's old and new z-index will have its z-index 
/// decremented by one.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="targetElement">
/// The element to be sent to the front of the z-order.
/// </param>
public void BringToFront(UIElement element)
{
  this.UpdateZOrder(element, true);
}

/// <summary>
/// Assigns the element a z-index which will ensure that 
/// it is behind every other element in the Canvas.
/// The z-index of every element whose z-index is between 
/// the element's old and new z-index will have its z-index 
/// incremented by one.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="targetElement">
/// The element to be sent to the back of the z-order.
/// </param>
public void SendToBack(UIElement element)
{
  this.UpdateZOrder(element, false);
}

#endregion // BringToFront / SendToBack

#region ElementBeingDragged

/// <summary>
/// Returns the UIElement currently being dragged, or null.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Note to inheritors: This property exposes a protected 
/// setter which should be used to modify the drag element.
/// </remarks>
public UIElement ElementBeingDragged
{
  get
  {
    if (!this.AllowDragging)
      return null;
    else
      return this.elementBeingDragged;
  }
  protected set
  {
    if (this.elementBeingDragged != null)
      this.elementBeingDragged.ReleaseMouseCapture();

    if (!this.AllowDragging)
      this.elementBeingDragged = null;
    else
    {
      if (DragCanvas.GetCanBeDragged(value))
      {
        this.elementBeingDragged = value;
        this.elementBeingDragged.CaptureMouse();
      }
      else
        this.elementBeingDragged = null;
    }
  }
}

#endregion // ElementBeingDragged

#region FindCanvasChild

/// <summary>
/// Walks up the visual tree starting with the specified DependencyObject, 
/// looking for a UIElement which is a child of the Canvas.  If a suitable 
/// element is not found, null is returned.  If the 'depObj' object is a 
/// UIElement in the Canvas's Children collection, it will be returned.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="depObj">
/// A DependencyObject from which the search begins.
/// </param>
public UIElement FindCanvasChild(DependencyObject depObj)
{
  while (depObj != null)
  {
    // If the current object is a UIElement which is a child of the
    // Canvas, exit the loop and return it.
    UIElement elem = depObj as UIElement;
    if (elem != null && base.Children.Contains(elem))
      break;

    // VisualTreeHelper works with objects of type Visual or Visual3D.
    // If the current object is not derived from Visual or Visual3D,
    // then use the LogicalTreeHelper to find the parent element.
    if (depObj is Visual || depObj is Visual3D)
      depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
    else
      depObj = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(depObj);
  }
  return depObj as UIElement;
}

#endregion // FindCanvasChild

#endregion // Interface

#region Overrides

#region OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

  this.isDragInProgress = false;

  // Cache the mouse cursor location.
  this.origCursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

  // Walk up the visual tree from the element that was clicked, 
  // looking for an element that is a direct child of the Canvas.
  this.ElementBeingDragged = this.FindCanvasChild(e.Source as DependencyObject);
  if (this.ElementBeingDragged == null)
    return;

  // Get the element's offsets from the four sides of the Canvas.
  double left = Canvas.GetLeft(this.ElementBeingDragged);
  double right = Canvas.GetRight(this.ElementBeingDragged);
  double top = Canvas.GetTop(this.ElementBeingDragged);
  double bottom = Canvas.GetBottom(this.ElementBeingDragged);

  // Calculate the offset deltas and determine for which sides
  // of the Canvas to adjust the offsets.
  this.origHorizOffset = ResolveOffset(left, right, out this.modifyLeftOffset);
  this.origVertOffset = ResolveOffset(top, bottom, out this.modifyTopOffset);

  // Set the Handled flag so that a control being dragged 
  // does not react to the mouse input.
  e.Handled = true;

  this.isDragInProgress = true;
}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

#region OnPreviewMouseMove

protected override void OnPreviewMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPreviewMouseMove(e);

  // If no element is being dragged, there is nothing to do.
  if (this.ElementBeingDragged == null || !this.isDragInProgress)
    return;

  // Get the position of the mouse cursor, relative to the Canvas.
  Point cursorLocation = e.GetPosition(this);

  // These values will store the new offsets of the drag element.
  double newHorizontalOffset, newVerticalOffset;

  #region Calculate Offsets

  // Determine the horizontal offset.
  if (this.modifyLeftOffset)
    newHorizontalOffset = this.origHorizOffset + (cursorLocation.X - this.origCursorLocation.X);
  else
    newHorizontalOffset = this.origHorizOffset - (cursorLocation.X - this.origCursorLocation.X);

  // Determine the vertical offset.
  if (this.modifyTopOffset)
    newVerticalOffset = this.origVertOffset + (cursorLocation.Y - this.origCursorLocation.Y);
  else
    newVerticalOffset = this.origVertOffset - (cursorLocation.Y - this.origCursorLocation.Y);

  #endregion // Calculate Offsets

  if (!this.AllowDragOutOfView)
  {
    #region Verify Drag Element Location

    // Get the bounding rect of the drag element.
    Rect elemRect = this.CalculateDragElementRect(newHorizontalOffset, newVerticalOffset);

    //
    // If the element is being dragged out of the viewable area, 
    // determine the ideal rect location, so that the element is 
    // within the edge(s) of the canvas.
    //
    bool leftAlign = elemRect.Left < 0;
    bool rightAlign = elemRect.Right > this.ActualWidth;

    if (leftAlign)
      newHorizontalOffset = modifyLeftOffset ? 0 : this.ActualWidth - elemRect.Width;
    else if (rightAlign)
      newHorizontalOffset = modifyLeftOffset ? this.ActualWidth - elemRect.Width : 0;

    bool topAlign = elemRect.Top < 0;
    bool bottomAlign = elemRect.Bottom > this.ActualHeight;

    if (topAlign)
      newVerticalOffset = modifyTopOffset ? 0 : this.ActualHeight - elemRect.Height;
    else if (bottomAlign)
      newVerticalOffset = modifyTopOffset ? this.ActualHeight - elemRect.Height : 0;

    #endregion // Verify Drag Element Location
  }

  #region Move Drag Element

  if (this.modifyLeftOffset)
    Canvas.SetLeft(this.ElementBeingDragged, newHorizontalOffset);
  else
    Canvas.SetRight(this.ElementBeingDragged, newHorizontalOffset);

  if (this.modifyTopOffset)
    Canvas.SetTop(this.ElementBeingDragged, newVerticalOffset);
  else
    Canvas.SetBottom(this.ElementBeingDragged, newVerticalOffset);

  #endregion // Move Drag Element
}

#endregion // OnPreviewMouseMove

#region OnHostPreviewMouseUp

protected override void OnPreviewMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPreviewMouseUp(e);

  // Reset the field whether the left or right mouse button was 
  // released, in case a context menu was opened on the drag element.
  this.ElementBeingDragged = null;
}

#endregion // OnHostPreviewMouseUp

#endregion // Host Event Handlers

#region Private Helpers

#region CalculateDragElementRect

/// <summary>
/// Returns a Rect which describes the bounds of the element being dragged.
/// </summary>
private Rect CalculateDragElementRect(double newHorizOffset, double newVertOffset)
{
  if (this.ElementBeingDragged == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("ElementBeingDragged is null.");

  Size elemSize = this.ElementBeingDragged.RenderSize;

  double x, y;

  if (this.modifyLeftOffset)
    x = newHorizOffset;
  else
    x = this.ActualWidth - newHorizOffset - elemSize.Width;

  if (this.modifyTopOffset)
    y = newVertOffset;
  else
    y = this.ActualHeight - newVertOffset - elemSize.Height;

  Point elemLoc = new Point(x, y);

  return new Rect(elemLoc, elemSize);
}

#endregion // CalculateDragElementRect

#region ResolveOffset

/// <summary>
/// Determines one component of a UIElement's location 
/// within a Canvas (either the horizontal or vertical offset).
/// </summary>
/// <param name="side1">
/// The value of an offset relative to a default side of the 
/// Canvas (i.e. top or left).
/// </param>
/// <param name="side2">
/// The value of the offset relative to the other side of the 
/// Canvas (i.e. bottom or right).
/// </param>
/// <param name="useSide1">
/// Will be set to true if the returned value should be used 
/// for the offset from the side represented by the 'side1' 
/// parameter.  Otherwise, it will be set to false.
/// </param>
private static double ResolveOffset(double side1, double side2, out bool useSide1)
{
  // If the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Right attached properties 
  // are specified for an element, the 'Left' value is honored.
  // The 'Top' value is honored if both Canvas.Top and 
  // Canvas.Bottom are set on the same element.  If one 
  // of those attached properties is not set on an element, 
  // the default value is Double.NaN.
  useSide1 = true;
  double result;
  if (Double.IsNaN(side1))
  {
    if (Double.IsNaN(side2))
    {
      // Both sides have no value, so set the
      // first side to a value of zero.
      result = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      result = side2;
      useSide1 = false;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    result = side1;
  }
  return result;
}

#endregion // ResolveOffset

#region UpdateZOrder

/// <summary>
/// Helper method used by the BringToFront and SendToBack methods.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="element">
/// The element to bring to the front or send to the back.
/// </param>
/// <param name="bringToFront">
/// Pass true if calling from BringToFront, else false.
/// </param>
private void UpdateZOrder(UIElement element, bool bringToFront)
{
  #region Safety Check

  if (element == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("element");

  if (!base.Children.Contains(element))
    throw new ArgumentException("Must be a child element of the Canvas.", "element");

  #endregion // Safety Check

  #region Calculate Z-Indici And Offset

  // Determine the Z-Index for the target UIElement.
  int elementNewZIndex = -1;
  if (bringToFront)
  {
    foreach (UIElement elem in base.Children)
      if (elem.Visibility != Visibility.Collapsed)
        ++elementNewZIndex;
  }
  else
  {
    elementNewZIndex = 0;
  }

  // Determine if the other UIElements' Z-Index 
  // should be raised or lowered by one. 
  int offset = (elementNewZIndex == 0) ? +1 : -1;

  int elementCurrentZIndex = Canvas.GetZIndex(element);

  #endregion // Calculate Z-Indici And Offset

  #region Update Z-Indici

  // Update the Z-Index of every UIElement in the Canvas.
  foreach (UIElement childElement in base.Children)
  {
    if (childElement == element)
      Canvas.SetZIndex(element, elementNewZIndex);
    else
    {
      int zIndex = Canvas.GetZIndex(childElement);

      // Only modify the z-index of an element if it is  
      // in between the target element's old and new z-index.
      if (bringToFront && elementCurrentZIndex < zIndex ||
        !bringToFront && zIndex < elementCurrentZIndex)
      {
        Canvas.SetZIndex(childElement, zIndex + offset);
      }
    }
  }

  #endregion // Update Z-Indici
}

#endregion // UpdateZOrder

#endregion // Private Helpers
```

}